# Returning json from node js function

Tags: node.js, json

I am new to node js. I am trying to do scraping some value and name from the select tab from a particular website. My code as follows,

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const crio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://myurl';

const getOptions = function(optionName,ignoreOption) {
    return rp(url)
      .then(function(html) {

            crio('[name='+optionName+']', html).find('option').each((i,op) => {

                if(crio(op).text() != ignoreOption && crio(op).text() != '')
                    return {
                        name: crio(op).text(),
                        value: crio(op).val(),
                    };
            })

      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        //handle error
      });
  };

getOptions('test','-- Select company name --')
.then( data => 
console.log(data)
);
```

When I try to run this code, I am getting result as 'undefined'. How do I get the return json response from the getOptions function here?

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning a value inside your then function that is using crio.

Change

```
crio('[name='+optionName+']', html).find('option').each((i,op) => {
```

to

```
return crio('[name='+optionName+']', html).find('option').map((i,op) => {
```

Note the use of map instead of each.